# pylint- singleton comparison to - What is the purpose?

Tags: python, pep8

I was wondering why one should always compare to `None` using `is` ?

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
> is not, never the equality operators.
>
> Also, beware of writing if x when you really mean if x is not None --
> e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None
> was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such
> as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!

But there is not really an explanation for this guideline ...

Is the only reason 'readability' ? Because that is something very subjective.

Comment: `is` can not be overloaded; `==` and `!=` can.  it would be misleading to have `obj == None` to be `True` while `obj is None` is `False`. but as it is possible: with `is` you are always on the safe side.

Comment: It is also faster. But it's a *style guide*, it's going to make decisions about readability that not everyone is going to agree with.